# ios bar graph Thermometer with coreploat

Tags: ios7, graph, core-plot, bar-chart

I am Developing an Application which requires the following kind of the Thermometer. I am using the CorePlot.

Should I use the Core-plot or any other alternative or Any custom framework like this is already been developed?

[image: Thermometer in iOS]

Comment: If you have only this graph in your application then Why don't you use  simple UIViews and adjust its the length dynamically? that would be much easier. No need to use core plot.

Comment: Thanks actually i have Different Graphs in My Application thats why i am using the Core-Plot .so i am just conforming that is it Possible with Core-Plot

Comment: Ok ..Yes its definitely

Comment: ok Do you have any Sample or Tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I asked to use views because its easier and quick to implement. With core plot, It would be good if you go through documentation and understand how it works first. 
**"Vertical Bar Chart"** in the [Plot Gallery example](https://github.com/djw/core-plot/tree/master/examples) app demonstrates this. 
In your code, You need to set

CPBarPlot * barPlot = [CPBarPlot ...];

[barPlot setBarsAreHorizontal:YES];